# R zoomChart Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod

i've been trying to interactively zoom in certain parts of a chartSeries with `zoomChart` and `shiny`, but can't find the right solution. I would use `dateRangeInput` or a slider, but i'm not sure how to connect the zoomChart-option from `quantmod` with `shiny`. As you might have already assumed, I'm relatively new to shiny and very thankful for your advices!

edit: Data is in the xts-format.

MyCode:

```
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)

date_range <- as.POSIXct(index(data))
if (interactive()) {
  options(device.ask.default = FALSE)
  ui <- fluidPage(  
    titlePanel("Select Range to zoom-in:"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        dateRangeInput("Range", "Choose Date Range:", min=first(date_range),
                   max=last(date_range), format = "dd-mm-yyyy")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("Plot")
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
      chartSeries(data, type = c("auto", "candlesticks", "matchsticks",   "bars","line"), 
              theme=chartTheme("white"), name=paste(start(data), end(data),sep = " ")) 
      zoomChart(dateRangeInput) 
    })
  }
   shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: what is `date_range <- as.POSIXct(index(data))` supposed to be...

Comment: I am using xts data, so date_range should just be the dates-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you were very close. Note the changes in `dateRangeInput()`: The start and end argument are used instead of min, max. And then you can use the input on the server-side to use `zoom-chart`.

```
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)
getSymbols("YHOO")
data <- YHOO
date_range <- index(data)
if (interactive()) {
  options(device.ask.default = FALSE)
  ui <- fluidPage(  
    titlePanel("Select Range to zoom-in:"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        dateRangeInput("Range", "Choose Date Range:", start=first(date_range),
                       end=last(date_range), format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("Plot")
      )
    )
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
      chartSeries(data, type = c("auto", "candlesticks", "matchsticks",   "bars","line"), 
                  theme=chartTheme("white"), name=paste(start(data), end(data),sep = " ")) 
      zoomChart(paste(input$Range, collapse = "::")) 
    })

    observe({
      print(input$Range)
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

As @drmariod indicated It would be beneficial to have a fully reproducible exmaple, which was easy to get in this case via `getSymbols()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly! And thanks for the advise, i'll provide reproducible data next time.